# pass object to directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to do the following:

```
<my-directive my-object="{Code:'test'}"/>
```

Then convert the string to an object in the controller. 
Currently using JSON.parse

I know I can do this:

```
<my-directive my-object="{&quot;Code&quot;:&quot;test&quot;}"/>
```

But seems messy and hard to read

Any way to do this?

Comment: Why not declaring that in the controller `$scope.obj = {Code: 'test'};` and pass `my-object="obj"` ?

Comment: cos the goal is to try to do not have each of this objects in the scope. So that a person that does not know much about angular but has a certain understanding of html can produce that in a easy manner

Comment: And BTW, I think that if you declare the property in the directive's scope as `myObj = "="` then it should work just fine

Comment: it is defined as myObj= but still comes as string

Comment: Take a look at this example https://plnkr.co/edit/gAQOEBdTz5UQG6IOpzN0?p=preview I cahgned the plunker from the [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) so it will take the data directly from the view and it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty, but [it is valid](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-single-quoted) to simply do:

```
<my-directive my-object='{"Code":"test"}'/>
```